# What are the tasks we can perform using interceptors in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, interceptor, dio

I am confused about refresh token , access token etc. Is interceptors are only used for checking authentication ?

I found this in the internet ? can you explain it too?
Chart on interceptor:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

So not that long ago Auth0 has released an official package for authenticating.

It handles all the difficult processes by itself. The only thing you need to provide is your client_id and domain. You will receive an access_token in JWT form.

Here is a link to the package:
https://pub.dev/packages/auth0_flutter

It has been well documented. Also a lot of information is already available on the website of auth0 on access_tokens and refresh tokens.

I hope this makes it a little easier.